# JS redirecting to another page and appending class to one of its elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an 'a' tag,with clicking on it I'm redirecting to another page.But I want to select an element from that page and append class to it.

HTML:

```
<a href="another pages url">blah</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $("#elementsId").addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: is #elementsId in current page or target page?

Comment: Target page. Maybe i should load that pages data somehowe in my jquery code?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a URL link, the page is being refreshed and the current Jquery wont work anymore. You have to update your codes to determine the active `<a>` link according to the new target page URL on page load or on **DOM ready** not **onClick**.

The you have to set the **selected** class to the menu which has the found filename as href attribute.

find current url and set **selected** class for related link:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //Determine current page url
    var fullpath =window.location.pathname;
    var filename=fullpath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    //alert(filename);

    //Selects the proper a tag
    var currentLink=$('a[href="' + filename + '"]'); 
    currentLink.addClass("selected");
    }))
```